# How to change the header color of my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the header of a website (http://c.sitagabriel.com).

I don't know JavaScript only HTML and I cannot find the color (red) on any js file from `c.sitagabriel.com`.

I edited the `style.css` and it didn't change the color.

I also don't know which file to edit the code on.

Comment: Check with css header class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a JS problem.

In your style.css line 23, on the .header, you have :

`background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #D5D5D5 0%, #FCFCFC 100%);`

You can change the `background-image` property in something like `background-color:red`, and your header will be :

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Thank you, but I need to change this also: http://c.sitagabriel.com/services.html the services, photo gallery and contact pages too.

Comment: What do you want to change in these pages ? The only thing you have to change is the stylesheet file which is linked to your HTML page.

Comment: in those pages I want to change the header color to blue, to match the blue from the homepage. I changed the colors in the style.css but I didn't had any effect on those pages. I changed the color in .navbar-default to the blue color, but with no luck.

Comment: This isn't a quesiton of luck ! Maybe you're not editing the right element in your stylesheet. If you want to change the background color of an element, just edit `background` or `background-color` in the CSS file.

Comment: editing background and background-color in the CSS file, only changes the homepage header, I am trying to change the header on all pages, but I think there is another file which needs to be edited in order to change the color of the header of the services, photo gallery and contact pages.

Comment: Seems to be a template. If you don't know how it works, will be difficult to edit..

Comment: It's a template, but I don't know how it works. I only know HTML and a little  CSS. It is difficult to change the header color?

Comment: No it isn't :) You just have to learn some CSS rules, and how the div work. To help you, you can right click on the div you want to change (header or navbar for exemple), and select Inspect Element. You will know what is the name of the div you wanna edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change CSS for header class.
In CSS, changes are :

`.header
{ backgroud-color : red; }`